# Javascript Reduce function - concatenate duplicate key values as an array

Tags: javascript, json, reduce

Hi I'm using reduce to create a more usable JSON structure for the following data.

```
data = [
  { "0": "key1", "1": "value1" },
  { "0": "key2", "1": "value2" },
  { "0": "key3", "1": "value3" },
  { "0": "key1", "1": "value4" },
];
```

I used reduce for this, and here is how it looks.

```
reduce_data = data.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c["0"]] = c["1"];
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(reduce_data);
```

Output is as follows

```
{key1: "value4", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}
```

If you see Im missing key1 and its value1. I understand its by design, but Im wondering if there is a way for me to get

`{key1: "value1, value4", key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}`

Please let me know if I'm using reduce incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you need to see if the key already exists, and if it does, append the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific case you can do it like this:

```js
data = [
  { "0": "key1", "1": "value1" },
  { "0": "key2", "1": "value2" },
  { "0": "key3", "1": "value3" },
  { "0": "key1", "1": "value4" },
];

reduce_data = data.reduce((p, c) => {
  p[c["0"]] = p[c["0"]] ? p[c["0"]] + ", " + c["1"] : c["1"];
  return p;
}, {});
console.log(reduce_data);
```

Comment: The ternary here isn't very readable, but I guess it could be slightly shorter like so: `p[c["0"]] = p[c["0"]] ? p[c["0"]] + ", " + c["1"] : c["1"];`

Comment: Thank you! This worked. So now I see my Key has two values, comma separated. I can read this data easily. An additional question I have is, Is there a better way to represent this data? Like `"key1" :  {"key1_1": value1, "key1_2" : value2}`. Looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: I would use an array for each key since there could be multiple values. For example: { "key1": [ "value1", "value4" ], "key2": [ "value2" ], "key3":  [ "value3" ]}

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you are doing it right. The problem is that the 4th element also has `key1` which overrides the value with `value4`.

---

**Update**

I read the question too fast. A solution could be:

```
data.reduce(
  (result, { ['0']: key, ['1']: value }) => ({
    ...result, 
    [key]: [result[key], value].filter(Boolean).join(', ')
  }),
  {}
)
```

Another way (where the result would have the values as an array):

```
data.reduce(
  (result, { ['0']: key, ['1']: value }) => ({
    ...result, 
    [key]: [...(result[key] || []), value]
  }),
  {}
)
```

Comment: He knows that. The question is how to concatenate the values of duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the key exists or not and then append rather than assigning (which overrides the value).

Solution here for you...

```
data.reduce((p, c) => {
  if (p[c["0"]]) {
    p[c["0"]] += ", " + c["1"];
  } else {
    p[c["0"]] = c["1"];
  }

  return p;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it unless it's already there, in which case concat:

```js
data = [
    { "0": "key1", "1": "value1" },
    { "0": "key2", "1": "value2" },
    { "0": "key3", "1": "value3" },
    { "0": "key1", "1": "value4" },
  ];

  reduce_data = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c["0"]] = (p[c["0"]] || '').concat(", ", c["1"])
    return p;
  }, {});
  console.log(reduce_data);
```

You didn't really ask, but it might be easier to use if you push to an array:

```js
data = [
    { "0": "key1", "1": "value1" },
    { "0": "key2", "1": "value2" },
    { "0": "key3", "1": "value3" },
    { "0": "key1", "1": "value4" },
  ];

  reduce_data = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    (p[c["0"]] || (p[c["0"]] = [])).push(c["1"]);
    return p;
  }, {});
  console.log(reduce_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 destructirung assignment makes it a bit more clean:

```
var data = [{ "0": "key1", "1": "value1" }, { "0": "key2", "1": "value2" }, { "0": "key3", "1": "value3" },{ "0": "key1", "1": "value4" },];

var result = data.reduce((p, {"0":key, "1": val}) => {

    if (!p.hasOwnProperty(key)) p[key] = [];
    p[key].push(val);
    return p;

}, {});

console.log(result);
```